# Prevent edge from cutting through node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I got the following TikZ Graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm,thick,
node/.style={shape = rectangle,draw}]
  \node[node] (en) {ENTRY};
  \node[node, label=180:$B_1$:] (1) [below of=en]{
    \begin{lstlisting}
p = 0.0
i = 0
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node, label=180:$B_2$:] (2) [below of=1]{
    \begin{lstlisting}
if n<=i goto EXIT
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node, label=180:$B_3$:] (3) [below of=2]{
    \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
i =  i + 1
$t_1$ =  a[i]
$t_2$ =  b[i]
$t_3$ =  $t_2$ * $t_3$
p =  p + $t_3$
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node, label=180:$B_4$:, anchor=north east] (4) [below of=3]{
    \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
goto $B_2$
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node] (ex) [below of = 4] {EXIT};

  \path (en) edge (1);  
  \path (1)  edge (2);
  \path (2)  edge (3);  
  \path (3)  edge (4);
  \path (4)  edge (ex);
  \path (4) edge [bend right] (2);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the edge from node (4) to node (2) cuts right through node (3). I would love to define some kind of anchor for the edge like the top right corner of node (4) and the bottom right corner of node (2). I found an attribute called anchor that can be set but doing so results in no change.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate (as it seems to be a rather common problem) but my search did not yield any useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
\draw (4.east) -- ++(2cm,0) |- (2);
```

you get

[image]

With

```
\draw (4.20) to [bend right,looseness=1.5] (2.350);
```

you get

[image]

And with

```
\draw (4.east) to[bend right] (2.east);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,listings}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm,thick,
node/.style={shape = rectangle,draw}]
  \node[node] (en) {ENTRY};
  \node[node, label=180:$B_1$:] (1) [below of=en]{
    \begin{lstlisting}
p = 0.0
i = 0
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node, label=180:$B_2$:] (2) [below of=1]{
    \begin{lstlisting}
if n<=i goto EXIT
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node, label=180:$B_3$:] (3) [below of=2]{
    \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
i =  i + 1
$t_1$ =  a[i]
$t_2$ =  b[i]
$t_3$ =  $t_2$ * $t_3$
p =  p + $t_3$
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node, label=180:$B_4$:, anchor=north east] (4) [below of=3]{
    \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
goto $B_2$
    \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \node[node] (ex) [below of = 4] {EXIT};

  \path (en) edge (1);
  \path (1)  edge (2);
  \path (2)  edge (3);
  \path (3)  edge (4);
  \path (4)  edge (ex);
  \draw (4.east) -- ++(2cm,0) |- (2);
  %\draw (4.20) to [bend right,looseness=1.5] (2.350);
  %\draw (4.east) to[bend right] (2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Couldn't hope for more.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify wich anchor to use directly in the node id, like this (for instance):

```
  \path (4.east) edge [bend right] (2.south east);
```

See section 17.11 (p246) of [the pgf manual](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), titled *Using Nodes as Coordinates*.